# How do I search a Ruby hash from an array of values, and then return a hash based on the findings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

Here's an example hash and an example array to search in the hash:

```
nicknames = { "Black Mamba" => "Kobe Bryant",
              "Half Man Half Amazing" => "Vince Carter",
              "The Big Fundamental" => "Tim Duncan",
              "Big Ticket" => "Kevin Garnett",
              "Obi-Wan Ginobili" => "Manu Ginobili",
              "The Answer" => "Allen Iverson" }

names = [ "Vince Carter", "Manu Ginobili", "Allen Iverson" ]
```

I want to return:

```
selected = { "Half Man Half Amazing" => "Vince Carter", "Obi-Wan Ginobili" => "Manu Ginobili", "The Answer" = "Allen Iverson" }
```

What's a good way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What about Chris Kaman, variously known as "The Caveman",  "Shaggy", "The Zombie" and "Crazy Clown", and many other players with multiple nicknames? A few of the more memorable ones: "Pistol Pete" (Pete Maravich), “The Microwave” (Vinnie Johnson), “Birdman” (Chris Andersen), “The Worm” (Dennis Rodman), "Hair Canada" (Steve Nash), “Da White Howard” (David Lee).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Haha, those nicknames are great too. I wanted to keep the example short like "Mugsy" Bogues.

Comment: At the other end there's "Bob" (Robert Pettit)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
nicknames.select { |key, value| names.include?(value) }
```

(copy-paste the code you provided and mine in your IRB console and you'll see it working).

Comment: If all NBA players are to be included in `nicknames`, perhaps: `require 'set'; snames = names.to_set; nicknames.select { |key, value| snames.include?(value) }`.

Answer (score 3):

If the values in the hash are unique, then you can reverse the keys and the values. MrYoshiji's code works, but here is a more efficient way.

```
hash = nicknames.invert
names.to_enum.with_object({}){|k, h| h[hash[k]] = k}
```

Comment: `names` is an array, why we need to do `to_a` on it?

Comment: @WandMaker I made a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Trying to get the reputation, huh? ahah I'm joking, thanks for your input, I didn't know about this solution which is more efficient. +1

Comment: Could you explain(or prove) why this is more efficient than @MrYoshiji's  answer?

Comment: No matter what approach is taken, there's a problem with duplicate values, so your proviso might instead be a general warning. A variant: `hash.values_at(*names).zip(names).to_h`. @MrYoshjii, yes, sawa is after points. His seemingly abrasive manner is designed for that. In real life, he's reticent and retiring.

Comment: @Doguita, that depends in part on whether the inverted hash is to be used just once or multiple times with different values of `names`. For one-time use, the setup time to construct `hash` may not make this method faster than Mr Y's way. (Even then, Y performs the ponderous `names.include?(value)` for every value of `nicknames` until a match is found. As I noted in a comment, that could be sped up by using a set.) If the hash is to be constructed multiple times for different values of `names`, it's no contest, as sawa only has to look up the value of `hash` for each element of `names`.

Comment: That's make sense. I was thinking about the one time use case only. Thanks @CarySwoveland

Comment: `Array#include?` is less efficient than `Hash#[]`.

Comment: sawa, I'd think that would depend on how far, on average, `include?` must go before finding a match (or determine there is no match), which is data-dependent. Assuming `nicknames` will be much larger than `names`, `include?` would traverse the entire array (and return `nil`) most of the time, supporting your conclusion.